# TF/Keras Sparse categorical crossentropy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have data which is loosely labelled with a single category "importance".
Basically the labels are [0..5] and have same meaning - they are denoting same event only with different prominence.
Picture a sunny beach  and that your data is force of the waves rolling on to the sand (or another interpretation - distance from the edge of the beach each wave travels and separated into 5 bins/categories)..

My question - if I use sparse categorical crossentropy to predict waves category, will TF/Keras model "understand" that 5 is larger (better/more informative) than 4 and 4 is larger than 3 etc..

Can it possibly deduce that label values are connected between themselves? That sequence of labels 1 2 3 4 5 aren't the same as 5 4 3 2 1 ?

Data supports the fact above but will the model figure that out? And what can I do to make this easier for the model?

Or in other words - what is the intrinsic implementation of sparse categorical crossentropy in the sense of interpreting categorical label value?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question. Here is my intuition about your problem. Sparse categorical cross-entropy threats each category as a distinct one. So, there is no connection between `1` which is `[0,1,0,0,0,0]` and `3` which is `[0,0,1,0,0,0]` assuming that your labels are `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`. On the other hand, your labels indicate the magnitude of a single event where `5` is the maximum and `0` is the minimum. Therefore, I would normalize your labels as:

```
labels = labels / max(labels)
```

and then compute the sigmoid cross entropy of the single event, where `1.0` indicates the highest probability and `0.0` the lowest. In that sense, your label would be in the following range `[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]`. You can do that in the following way:

```
# Random labels
labels = np.array([0, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5])
# Normalized labels
labels = labels / np.amax(labels)
# Random logits
logits = np.array([1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 0.2])
loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(loss)
```

Comment: no no gorjan - you are mixing up one hot categorical cross entropy with sparse cross entropy (which is int values like 1,2,3,4,5.. not 00001 00010 etc.. yeah? P.S. obv 000001 is not good idea to use for what I want, but I am hoping sparse can have it inherited in the algorithm.. or perhaps there is another way? I cant be the only one who has a task like that

Comment: From the documentation of `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`: Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in which the classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly one class). So no, not depending whether you use sparse categorical cross-entropy, or one hot categorical cross-entropy, there is no difference in how the labels are treated. In reality, the only difference between the sparse categorical cross entropy and categorical cross entropy is the format of true labels. In your case, you have a single event where the labels indicate the magnitude.

Comment: Even though I pretty sure that my intuition is right, let us wait to see other answers and other people's opinion on the matter. I am also wondering if maybe there is other interpretation of your problem and thus other solution.

Comment: its in the definition: https://keras.io/losses/ scroll down to see - When using the sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets should be **integer** targets. HTH

Comment: You are right about that. As mentioned in the comment, the difference is the format of the labels. However, [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) from the Tensorflow website provides the definition. Please check it out.